# How to put values from html rows to sql database?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```js
function addRow(tableID) {    
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "checkbox";
    element1.name="chkbox[]";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = rowCount;

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.name = "item";
    element2.size = "40";
    cell3.appendChild(element2);

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type = "text";
    element3.name = "qty";
    element3.style ="text-align: right";
    cell4.appendChild(element3);

}
```

I am creating a set of columns using this code and by using a button action I am adding such rows continuously to the page.

Now along with this, I want to simultaneously add these values to SQL database.
Plus whenever i revisit this page I should have the previously entered data.

The setup have 3 buttons `Delete Row`, `Add Row` and `Save`.
I want to get all the rows into Database once I click `Save`.

Comment: Question is tagged `php` and `html`.. so where is the corresponding code?

Comment: You will need to look into using ajax with PHP and then use PHP PDO to access and talk to the database.

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kLenBC4PRNtIsS-qFZAhJjaCH5IQYZ6-/view?usp=sharing) @B001ᛦ here's the complete code.
I want item cost and current data in database. Thanks